# What essential preparations should I take before winter driving?

Tags: safety, winter

Two years ago I published [this blog post](http://infosecfrog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/being-prepared.html) on being prepared for the winter, covering off:

- Practice
- Planning the route
- Mechanical
- Supplies
- Geek essentials

Some of these might be a bit tongue in cheek, but broadly speaking I think I got the basics.

But as I drive a lot, including through the winter, my question is: have I missed anything essential from a mechanical, electrical or drivetrain viewpoint that might risk my life or safety?

Comment: Just to focus the answers, you might need to specify "winter".  Around here (Rhode Island, USA) winter is nothing special most of the time.  Siberia winter is a different story.  Are you talking about a winter where you'd die of exposure?  Or would only be inconvenienced waiting for a tow truck?

Comment: That is an excellent point - based on the winters of 09-10 and 10-11, Scottish winters can be a 'die of exposure' scenario as tow trucks couldn't get through the snow.

Comment: Your question needs to be reasonably scoped so that it can be practically answered. You should focus questions that you ask to one topic for example, which mechanical supplies should I keep in my car during winter. Your question as it is it too broad and cannot be reasonably answered. mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion I would have is to allow your car to warm up before driving. Modern cars are eons better at this, but nothing short of a wreck is harder on a car than being driven when the engine's oil isn't up to temperature (and bearing clearances are off, etc.).

How long is up for debate. I believe the general consensus is at least a couple minutes.

Also, avoiding high RPMs and loads until the temperature gauge reads normal is also recommended.

Comment: Good call - can't think why I hadn't included this!

Comment: Doesn't have much to do with being prepared for the winter, as it does car upkeep.

Comment: A proper oil for the temperature is key, really.  If you're running too thick of an oil you're going to suffer hard starts and increased wear.

Comment: There we go. That's what I meant.